# ¿Como obtengo un solo resultado entre varias columnas en una misma tabla?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

ando perdido con el tema de PDO estuve leyendo pero no encuentro la forma de yo poder hacer lo siguiente.

Como puedo obtener un solo resultado de varias columnas en una misma tabla:

La tabla es **ct_datos**

Quiero obtener el resultado del mejor jugador es decir, que al hacer una consulta se fije quien tiene mas **ELO** y **RANGO**, eso si destaco que el **RANGO** seria primordial, primero verifica que **RANGO** es si todos tienen **0** luego se fije el **ELO** quien tenga mas **ELO** se lo mostraría con el resultado de la columna **PERSONAJE**, pero si uno tiene el **RANGO** en **1** y los demas **0** se muestre primero el que tenga el **RANGO** mas alto.

[image: Estructura de la tabla ct_datos]

Como veran El Personaje JkDev tiene **2** de **ELO** y **0** de **RANGO** y debajo lo sigue Pepeitaka con **0** **ELO** y **0** **RANGO** entonces lo que debo de hacer es mostrar el que tenga mejor estadistica con el nombre del **PERSONAJE** como resultado

[image]

```
<?php
$sentencia= $db_ffa->prepare("SELECT Elo, Rango, Personaje FROM ct_datos ORDER BY Rango DESC LIMIT 1");
$sentencia->execute();
```

Desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Podrias mostrarnos que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Ya edite la publicación pero te lo dejo aqui






<?php
$sentencia= $db_ffa->prepare("SELECT Elo, Rango, Personaje FROM ct_datos ORDER BY Rango DESC LIMIT 1");
$sentencia->execute();

Comment: `SELECT Elo, Rango, Personaje FROM ct_datos ORDER BY Rango DESC Elo DESC LIMIT 1` debería ser suficiente.

Comment: Gracias Triby, pero recien pude entrar a la pc y colo que como decias lo deje así >

<?php
$sentencia= $db_ffa->prepare("SELECT Elo, Rango, Personaje FROM ct_datos ORDER BY Rango DESC Elo DESC LIMIT 1");
$sentencia->execute();

Me sale error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solamente ordena los datos dos veces en tu query de la siguiente manera:

```
$sentencia= $db_ffa->prepare("SELECT `Elo`, `Rango`, `Personaje` FROM `ct_datos` ORDER BY `Rango` DESC, `Elo` DESC LIMIT 1");
$sentencia->execute();
```

Explicacion:

```
SELECT `Elo`, `Rango`, `Personaje` FROM `ct_datos` ORDER BY `Rango` DESC, `Elo` DESC LIMIT 1`
```

Aqui le estas diciendo a la base de datos que selecione las columnas elo,rango y personaje de la tabla ct_datos y que los ordene por rango descendiente. Esto ordena los datos siendo el primer renglon el rango mas alto. Despues le dices que una vez que los datos esten ordenados por rango, ahora los ordene por elo sin afectar el rango. Esto te da como resultado los rangos de mas alto a mas bajo y cada rango de mas alto a mas bajo elo. Finalmente le dices a la base de datos que solo te de el primer renglon con limit 1.

Y eso es todo. La base de datos de devuelve el jugador con mas alto rango primero y con elo mas alto.

**NOTA**: La coma `,` entre `DESC` y ``Elo `DESC` es importante, sin ella te saldra error!

Comment: Hola @ajsoler gracias por tu respuesta hice lo que me has dicho hasta he puesto el código pero sale el siguiente error.

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) in C:\wamp64\www\demo\head.php on line 21.

```$sentencia3= $db_ffa->prepare("SELECT (`Elo`, `Rango`, `Personaje`) FROM `ct_datos` ORDER BY `Rango` DESC, `Elo` DESC LIMIT 1");```

Comment: haz el query directamente en phpmyadmin y si la base de datos te da el jugador on rango y elo mas alto sin ningun error, entonces quiere decir que estas preparando tus declaracion incorrectamente en tu codigo de php.

Comment: Sigue tirando error en el PHPMyADMIN https://prnt.sc/tehsll dejo una vista previa, esta raro   ```MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1241 - Operando debe tener 1 columna(s)```

Comment: Corregido habia que quitar los ( ), gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Ok he corregido tambien la respuesta a esta pregunta. Saludos.